# Automate text formatting with csv/excel data

Tags: excel, csv, text-files

I am looking for a software that can output separate text files from each row of a excel table / csv.
I want to create multiple text files for dokuwiki.
The data from the csv will populate a preformatted text file template.

I am confident I can write a python script that can do that but I was wondering if there is a software that can make this task quicker, better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you ar looking for?

```
Sub aru()
Dim row As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim file As Worksheet
Dim col As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim dir As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
dir = "C:\txt\" 'Set here the folder you want to save the files
i = 1
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For row = 1 To lastrow 'Define here the starting row
    lastcol = Cells(row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheets.Add.Name = "File" & i
    Set file = Sheets("File" & i)
    For col = 1 To lastcol
        file.Cells(1, col).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
    Next col
    file.SaveAs dir & file.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
    i = i + 1
    file.Delete
Next row
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It also saves the "master" sheet as another name. You can close without saving in the end. Just save the way you want before you run the code.